# Prevent only one Page from back gesture

Tags: flutter

i know about the `WillPopScope`, but i need a solution so only the first welcome page cant be reached after login.
How can i approach this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need pushReplacement method with _completeLogin function like in documents. Check from here; https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushReplacement.html

```
onWillPop: () async {
    if (Navigator.of(context).userGestureInProgress)
      return false;
    else
      return true;
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the pushReplacement method of the Navigator to replace your welcome page with the login page.

Comment: now, when the back gesture is triggered, the whole app closes. Is there a way to prevent this as well?

Comment: You can add the lines which I added to my answer to your welcome page it will prevent to back gesture.

Comment: Yes, you can now use the WillPopScope method. Check this article : https://medium.com/@iamatul_k/flutter-handle-back-button-in-a-flutter-application-override-back-arrow-button-in-app-bar-d17e0a3d41f

Comment: I tried the WillPopScope before but everytime I directed to another page via the drawer (all pushReplacements), the gesture was available again. So do I have to implement the WillPopScope to every Scaffold?

Comment: Yes you need to add each new page because onWillPop effects only it's child.